# Need equivalent JPA query for a sql query

Tags: jpa

I want to write equivalent JPA query to the following sql query, Could you please help?

```
    select s.id, s.spec_system, s.pc, s.end_date 
    FROM context_service_subscription s
    LEFT JOIN ctxsrv_sub_spec_variants sv
    ON s.id = sv.subscription_id
    LEFT JOIN ctxsrv_sub_change_variants cv
    ON s.id = cv.subscription_id
    WHERE s.end_date >= now()
    order by s.id

I have tried below, but does not work

    <named-query name="findAllSubscriptionVariant">
      <query>SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Subscription s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.specVariants sv LEFT JOIN FETCH 
      s.changeVariants cv order by s.id</query>
    </named-query>
```

Answer (score 0):

can this

```
select s.id, s.spec_system, s.pc, s.end_date 
FROM context_service_subscription s
LEFT JOIN ctxsrv_sub_spec_variants sv
ON s.id = sv.subscription_id
LEFT JOIN ctxsrv_sub_change_variants cv
ON s.id = cv.subscription_id
WHERE s.end_date >= now()
order by s.id
```

be rewritten into

```
select s.id, s.spec_system, s.pc, s.end_date 
FROM context_service_subscription s
WHERE s.end_date >= now()
order by s.id
```

?
if yes your jpql query should become

```
select s.id, s.spec_system, s.pc, s.end_date 
FROM Subscription s
WHERE s.end_date >= now()
order by s.id
```

where you should change id, spec_system, pc, end_date into the names of the members of Subscription

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, I need to fetch two of my child objects in the JPA query, I mean ctxsrv_sub_spec_variants  and ctxsrv_sub_change_variants were child objects, it has one-two many relations with Fetch type LAZY. How write JPA query including the child objects ??

Comment: I need parent records and associated child records in a JPA query.

Comment: @JayT use join fetch in the from